# How to swap every 2 letters in a String? - Java

Tags: java, nested-loops

So I'm currently working on a personal project and I made a program that tries to swap every 2 letter in a given string.

So I want the output like this:

***(Note Input String is "abllte")***

```
ballet
```

So I wrote this method

```java
public static String codeString(String input) {
      String firstLetter = "";
      String secoundLetter = "";
      String result = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < input.length()-1; i++){
         for(int c = 0; c < i; c = c +2)
         {  
            firstLetter = input.substring(c,c + 1);
            secoundLetter = input.substring(c + 1, c + 2); 
            
         }
         result = result + secoundLetter + firstLetter;
      }
      return result;
   }
```

But I get this output:

```
ababllll
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can invest some of your time in regex. With this tool your could could look like `String result = input.replaceAll("(.)(.)", "$2$1");`.

Comment: @Pshemo Amazing Comment! But I want to only use nested loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the point of your nested for loop is. You can do this with just one loop.

```
public static String codeString(String input) {
   String firstLetter = "";
   String secoundLetter = "";
   String result = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < input.length()-1; i+=2){

      firstLetter = input.substring(i,i+1);
      secoundLetter = input.substring(i+1,i+2);
      result = result + secoundLetter + firstLetter;

   }

   return result;
}
```

If your input string has an odd number of characters, you'll have to append the extra last character.

```
public static String codeString(String input) {
   String firstLetter = "";
   String secoundLetter = "";
   String result = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < input.length()-1; i+=2){

      firstLetter = input.substring(i, i+1);
      secoundLetter = input.substring(i+1, i+2);
      result = result + secoundLetter + firstLetter;

   }

   if(input.length() % 2 == 1)
      result += input.substring(input.length()-1, input.length());

   return result;
}
```

Comment: It works but, when I call this method codeString(codeString("beautiful")); it returns 'beautifu' not 'beautiful'. May you please fix it and I will accept your answer right away

Comment: I added the extra odd character

Comment: Thank you so much I will accept your answer right now!

Answer (score 3):

You only need one loop.  This works for both even and odd length character strings.

- first, the methods used return the `StringBuilder` in its current modified state.
- So `sb.insert(i, sb.charAt(i+1))` inserts the char at `i+1` at `i`
- So if `sb` contained `ab`,  `StringBuilder`  would now contain `bab`
- insert returns the modifed `StringBuilder` so now `sb.deleteCharAt(i+2)` deletes the second `a` (the one that was just copied).
- this is then repeated until all characters are swapped.
- Because of the constant inserting and deletion of characters this is not very efficient.

```
for (String s : new String[] { "abcdefg", "abcdefgh" }) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 1; i += 2) {
        sb.insert(i, sb.charAt(i + 1)).deleteCharAt(i + 2);
    }
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + sb);
}
```

Prints

```
abcdefg -> badcfeg
abcdefgh -> badcfehg
```

For a more efficient algorithm, this would be the way to go. It's also much more intuitive.

```
for (String s : new String[] { "abcdefg", "abcdefgh" }) {
    char ch[] = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length - 1; i+=2) {
        char c = ch[i];
        ch[i] = ch[i + 1];
        ch[i + 1] = c;
    }
    String d = String.valueOf(ch);
    
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + d);
}
```

This prints the same as above.

Comment: `StringBuilder` option can also be optimized by initializing it empty then in the loop: `sb.append(s.charAt(i+1)).append(s.charAt(i));`

Comment: True.  But my goal here was to do in place modification,

Comment: With Java `String` there is no in-place anyway due to the immutability. Either using `char[]` or `StringBuilder` is just better.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a nested loop. Change the outer loop to step by `2` i.e. `i = i + 2` and remove the inner loop.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(codeString("abllte"));
    }

    public static String codeString(String input) {
        String firstLetter = "";
        String secondLetter = "";
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i = i + 2) {
            firstLetter = input.substring(i, i + 1);
            secondLetter = input.substring(i + 1, i + 2);
            result = result + secondLetter + firstLetter;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ballet
```

**An alternative approach:**

You can create a function with two parameters: `input` string as the first parameter and `n` as the second parameter, where every `n` characters in the `input` string need to be reversed.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(codeString("abllte", 1));
        System.out.println(codeString("abllte", 2));
        System.out.println(codeString("abllte", 3));
        System.out.println(codeString("abllte", 4));
    }

    public static String codeString(String input, int n) {
        if (n <= input.length() / 2) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - n + 1; i = i + n) {
                result.append(new StringBuilder(input.substring(i, i + n)).reverse());
            }
            return result.toString();
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abllte
ballet
lbaetl
abllte
```